# Gerar colunas com repeat Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Não estou conseguindo gerar essas colunas dinamicamente com o `p:repeat` do Primefaces.

Não há como fazer isso no Primefaces? Ou não há como fazer isso? Existe uma solução melhor?

O problema é o seguinte, tenho um array com os cabeçalhos que preciso pra gerar as colunas e dependendo de como esteja esse array, serão geradas `n` counas.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{managedbean.dados}" var="dado">
    <p:column headerText="Header 1">
        <h:outputText value="#{dado.nome}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:repeat value="#{managedbean.colunas}" var="coluna">
        <p:column headerText="#{coluna}">
            //por enquanto ainda não fiz a lógica para pegar a coluna correta que vou extrair de 'dado'
        </p:column>
    </p:repeat>
</p:dataTable>
```

Situação exemplo:

Se eu tenho o array `colunas` da seguinte forma:

```
colunas[0] = "coluna0" 
colunas[1] = "coluna1" 
colunas[2] = "coluna2"
```

Eu iria querer que fossem geradas 3 colunas na tabela, a partir desse array

```
          DataTable
Header1 | coluna0 | coluna1 | coluna2
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza se funcionaria. Mas vc já tem os dados formados e quer exibir as colunas de forma condicional? (Usando o exemplo clássico de Pessoa Física e Pessoa Jurídica, exibir uma coluna com o CPF e outra com o CNPJ, sendo que os atributos já existem na entidade). Se for isso, creio que seria melhor usar o rendered no p:column.

Comment: @MarcusMartins vou melhorar o post, não é somente isso, mas eu irei precisar do `rendered`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só usar o `<p:columns>`, passando o array pela variável `value` e usando a variável `var`

```
<p:columns value="#{managedbean.colunas}" var="coluna" headerText="#{coluna}">
    <h:outputText value="valor desejado"/>
</p:columns>
```